# How to diagnose SSH login issues and general slowdowns on an Ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, performance

I'll preface that I get this is a really vague title, I'm just not sure where to even begin debugging.

I have an Ubuntu server running in my house and every while (say couple weeks?) I no longer am able to SSH into it, and web services running on it become super slow to respond/load (and some like Plex just fail altogether). The only solution is to reboot the machine.

This has been happening for a while now, I was hoping it was a transient issue that would go away but since it's continuing to happen I figure it's time to investigate.

Unfortunately I have no idea where to start, other than I have a hunch that it might be file system related. I don't think this is due to running out of disk space as there is ample space left, but maybe something like file locks etc.?

I do know that when it's in this state and I try to SSH, in the verbose output I see that authentication succeeds and then it fails to make a tunnel.

As for the web services running on it, I can ping them and get a response, but trying to load them in browser will take a long time and timeout or some parts of the services will fail (e.g. the frontend loads but not the API servers).

Does anyone have any tips on how to debug this further, like what logs to look at after a reboot?

EDIT: Adding some more system information
Ubuntu version:

```
❯ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Filesystem utilization:

```
❯ sudo df -h
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                      3.2G  3.9M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root  108G   32G   71G  32% /
tmpfs                       16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
hdd1:hdd2:ssd1:ssd2        3.3T  1.5T  1.7T  47% /servercontent
/dev/sdb1                  458G   28K  435G   1% /drives/ssd1
/dev/sdd1                  916G  287G  583G  33% /drives/ssd2
/dev/sda1                  511M  6.1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/sdc1                  1.8T  1.2T  602G  66% /drives/hdd1
tmpfs                      3.2G   80K  3.2G   1% /run/user/127
overlay                    108G   32G   71G  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ad3e5520b602aac865393564e099a59158f2fd6a131a4838cbfd18f703910607/merged
overlay                    108G   32G   71G  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/075e3ff738c8a360ddd2b26675a0365d842697b70db25a697444cd841430cbf8/merged
overlay                    108G   32G   71G  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/f99832362501221123e3561b85ab0d372c95db4b10db0f3ddbcccc8934a7ca1a/merged
overlay                    108G   32G   71G  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/63dc18707df2a50bd64d9d6c60de5864d0581f75ef5e888d03663d7fa12ba75b/merged
overlay                    108G   32G   71G  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/3c263c3f057b75df597e7eba9e9f19be4d71dbf5820ac7ea7992515801629ffc/merged
overlay                    108G   32G   71G  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/f5da10200016856e413de381b6e6115c9a41db8af09548d6704d91282abe2e24/merged
overlay                    108G   32G   71G  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/2a1e9b0f635a9d6241e434d534ac80375795ce333e494a8069341d0a07dec8b8/merged
overlay                    108G   32G   71G  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/88f615466d53a3c8f0ea8f191b66fee28bc43cec762df3ddeef921d8a4444de7/merged
overlay                    108G   32G   71G  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/1e50fd8513db5f2658f6dd33c04652a536300b613a86d04b871f35f29ad555b0/merged
tmpfs                      3.2G   72K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000
overlay                    108G   32G   71G  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/8aaee754a8dac797fbc81c921c539f8468f4642e745024fbd52725dc49ac30a2/merged
overlay                    108G   32G   71G  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/67727e0f2ad5814a6c5af75f49ffbf3bf9ad7a2717489d3ab96e545e344cdcbc/merged
overlay                    108G   32G   71G  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/3b832ada4fefc0ae27a057ea1abf0f5e2f29cdaf18a17798c95e5cf6a2697377/merged
overlay                    108G   32G   71G  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/0047d8aa3497c128ba370d9c8214feac7e9ee29e37a51523f9f471180fa0d08c/merged
overlay                    108G   32G   71G  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/357fce0647c1dcae36f3e88cd8211e5428557de274ec0c768716a9e1d2083f43/merged
overlay                    108G   32G   71G  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/10f7d0f3f4bf99d8db0fa56be7fc0168898049f37f6145d708bf9ab2f6b50da2/merged
overlay                    108G   32G   71G  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/80d00def351a1d2757876a1f721e562044841ec414ecb978c92e18ddc3970e31/merged
overlay                    108G   32G   71G  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e36747ccc1bfe474d5c67dba580d5268458c04ea34826750f5ff4806d6d84b00/merged
overlay                    108G   32G   71G  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/c39e6eabaa3792a0cd3f7e911f3b9975a851ee9a56c8496ca4691f8b8ade19cf/merged
overlay                    108G   32G   71G  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/66b1ae737a47d5a121e73df22d3766814dcd027994338616e8e235b15b101391/merged
overlay                    108G   32G   71G  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/0cf904916c2dd0438681c9ef6c3b32ccf17aeb18106a46f7d9d4e54ff08646f9/merged
overlay                    108G   32G   71G  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e24892e8b863c098808cf81282dfb0bae46db2c041108339593f5b368f821e00/merged
overlay                    108G   32G   71G  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/3a0f5209ce6c82c85c457c357a9c385385c5ed42b3397b9a148ebd746d42ed07/merged
overlay                    108G   32G   71G  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e50826c24be367368f75df81a125ef42f7333c66bb3af96cbc892822bccc0dab/merged
```

Swap info:

```
❯ swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size            Used            Priority
/dev/dm-1                               partition       2002940         0               -2
❯ free -mh
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31Gi       2.5Gi        21Gi        47Mi       7.8Gi        28Gi
Swap:          1.9Gi          0B       1.9Gi
```

Fstab (tried to use it to determine where the swap is, I assume on the SSD that the OS is installed on but I'm not sure):

```
❯ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=C3B4-3AA8  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID="de57c5c7-ac90-4df4-ac0f-e78ef0b02865"     /drives/ssd1    ext4    defaults        0       2
UUID="40bfa7ca-41f4-40ca-923b-a4f40c0c2ec0"     /drives/ssd2    ext4    defaults        0       2
UUID="c57c00dd-0bb0-4e79-a285-9ed3d3d02e55"     /drives/hdd1    ext4    defaults        0       2
#UUID="31018981-3e9c-4564-9237-f25628e0068d"    /drives/hdd2    ext4    defaults        0       2
/drives/*                                 /servercontent          fuse.mergerfs  allow_other,use_ino,cache.files=off,dropcacheonclose=true,category.create=mfs,minfreespace=10G,moveonenospc=true   0       0
```

Comment: First, please edit your question to add what version of Ubuntu this is happening on. “I do know that when it's in this state and I try to SSH, in the verbose output I see that authentication succeeds and then it fails to make a tunnel.” Please edit your question to share the verbose SSH output. It would be helpful to share! Also, is this server exposed to the world? It sounds like a crypto miner might have infected it via malware or something.

Comment: install atop, this tool takes a performance snapshot in a configurable interval. This also includes all processes. Afterwards you can analyze them.

Comment: If something leaked ram, forcing the swapfile to get used (and eventually filled), that could slow things down...  @Turdie does atop have an easy way to log things over time? It's screenshot and description (on Debian) sounds like top with a slower update interval, but if it logs say every 5-60 minutes that could be great to see a trend over hours/days.

Comment: Yes atop automatically logs the snapshot to /var/log. Atop can store system and process level statistics in a compressed binary format in a file.https://linux.die.net/man/1/atop

Comment: In order to store system- and process level statistics for long-term analysis (e.g. to check the system load and the active processes running yesterday between 3:00 and 4:00 PM), atop can store the system- and process level statistics in compressed binary format in a raw file with the flag -w followed by the filename.

Comment: This soinds an aweful lot like you have swap on hard drive and the system is swapping heavily.  Do you have physical access to the system?  How much memory and swap do you have?  Does the system have an hdd lught? Are you running ssd and/or hdd?   Is your SSH client Windows or Linux?

Comment: Its probably not thie issue, but what does S.M.A.R.T report on your disks health?

Comment: Not a psnacea, but what  has workef for me for a long tome on servers us reducing the amount of swap available (dont totally eliminate it though) and modifing vm.swappinedd to a low value - say 10. (From memory Ubuntu defaults to 60.  This makrs the system slightly slower as it gas less available memory to page but reduces swapping.  That said Ive never been locked out of a system with swap on ssd - unlike with swap on hdd.

Comment: Just updated with more information. I also installed atop so hopefully the next time the crash happens I'll have some days worth of atop snapshots to inspect. Also installed smartmonutils and ran tests on the drives, although my understanding is that smart tests are really only useful for HDDs, which should only have media files (the OS and swap should be on an SSD here)